# How to fix Kotlin libraries not resolving in IntelliJ in Kotlin code (in a java project)?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, kotlin, shared-libraries

I have two projects. One written fully in Kotlin that exports a Client artifact. I am trying to use the client in a second project that has a mix of java/kotlin code.

In the java classes I have no problem importing the kotlin files for use, but in any kotlin files, IntelliJ cannot resolve the imports. All the other kotlin code works fine and I can compile on the command line via maven with no problems. It's *just* an issue with IntelliJ not recognizing the package I'm looking for.

I see the package in both my maven toolbar as well as in the external libraries listed in the project. I've inspected the jars and sure enough the file I expect `com/foo/bar/BazClient.class` is present, but 
`import com.foo.bar.BazClient` tells me the package `bar` (the code from the other project) does not exist. The very same import statement works just fine in java code.

Further adding to my problems the exact same java class that imports this client, if I convert to kotlin using IJ's builtin method, fails to compile in IntelliJ. The "build project" action completes successfully with no warnings/errors.

Kotlin client is defined as:

```
package com.foo.bar

import retrofit2.http.GET

interface BazClient {
    @GET("/v1/fuzz")
    fun getFuzz(): Call<FuzzResponse>
}
```

Working java code:

```java
package com.whodat.wat;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import com.foo.bar.BazClient;

@Singleton
public class CallTheService {
    private final BazClient bazClient;

    public CallTheService(BazClient bazClient) {
        this.bazClient = bazClient;
    }

    public FuzzResponse callIt() throws IOException {
        return bazClient.getFuzz().execute().body();
    }
}
```

Failing kotlin code:

```
package com.whodat.wat

import javax.inject.Singleton
import com.foo.bar.BazClient // "bar" is red in editor

@Singleton
// Can't resolve "BazClient" here 
class CallTheService(private val bazClient: BazClient) {

    fun callIt(): FuzzResponse {
        return bazClient.getFuzz().execute().body()!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Imports might not all be 100% correct obviously, just a toy example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: So the Java  version and Kotlin version are in the same package? You just converted it, right?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a problem in publishing the client artifact. We were using the maven shade and jar plugins to create the jars and was leading to many kotlin_modules in the jar which were confusing IJ

```
META-INF/client.kotlin_module
META-INF/descriptors.jvm.kotlin_module
META-INF/descriptors.kotlin_module
META-INF/descriptors.runtime.kotlin_module
META-INF/deserialization.kotlin_module
META-INF/kotlin-reflect-api.kotlin_module
META-INF/metadata.jvm.kotlin_module
META-INF/metadata.kotlin_module
META-INF/util.runtime.kotlin_module
META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module
META-INF/kotlin-stdlib_coroutinesExperimental.kotlin_module
META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module
META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common-coroutines.kotlin_module
META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module
META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module
```

Removing those from the client build seems to have cleared things up, and now we just have the one client.kotlin_module.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28219) in Jetbrains issue tracker. The ticket has not been resolved yet, but support said:

> This is a known problem since the 1.2.50 release of the Kotlin plugin:
>   [KT-25709](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25709). As a workaround, please stop bundling the Kotlin
>   runtime in the dependency jar (i.e. everything under the package
>   kotlin should be removed from the jar)